# Angular4 reporting tool

Tags: angular, reporting

I'm looking for a free component to generate reports on Angular apps with web api backend. Reports like product sales, inventory and so on. Can't find anything.

Very strange.

Answer (score 3):

You could generate reports on the api side and download them to the client side. I use reportlab for this on a Django REST api backend and download the generated PDF's to the client SPA.

Comment: Seems to be an interesting tool, but just references to the Python world...

Comment: Correct. But just to point out that you can look for a backend tool for this.

Answer (score 0):

**fng-reports**

Plugin for forms-angular that adds Reporting capability, with grid output, totals, drill-downs (to other, more specific, reports or to the form that the data can be amended in), export to PDF and CSV

https://github.com/forms-angular/fng-reports